# Drawing arrow between subfigures in scaleboxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, subcaption, scalebox

I am trying to connect points inside separate tikz images with arrow. The overlay option works very well, but the images must be scaled to fit on the slide (I use them in beamer presentation). However, when I use scalebox for the plots the arrow is drawn on the original (unscaled) coordinates. Scaling the arrow does not work either. Is there I way to solve this issue (maybe without using scalebox)?

Thanks for any answer.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}    
        \scalebox{0.65}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \tikzset{point/.style = {circle, fill=black, draw=black, inner sep=2pt}} % Points
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](-0.5,0)--(6,0) node[right]{$x$}; % Axis X
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](0,-0.5)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$}; % Axis Y
        \node[point, label=above:A] (A) at (2.5,2.5) {}; % Point A
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth} 
        \scalebox{0.65}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \tikzset{point/.style = {circle, fill=black, draw=black, inner sep=2pt}} % Points
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](-0.5,0)--(6,0) node[right]{$x$}; % Axis X
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](0,-0.5)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$}; % Axis Y
        \node[point, label=above:B] (B) at (2.5,2.5) {}; % Point B
        \end{tikzpicture}}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
          \path[->,red,thick] (A) edge [bend right] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Don't use `scalebox`, but `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65,remember picture]`, because I think Ti*k*Z lose the reference inside a box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only point not affected by `\scalebox` is `(current bounding box.south west)`.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}    
        \scalebox{0.65}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \tikzset{point/.style = {circle, fill=black, draw=black, inner sep=2pt}} % Points
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](-0.5,0)--(6,0) node[right]{$x$}; % Axis X
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](0,-0.5)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$}; % Axis Y
        \node[point, label=above:A] (A) at (2.5,2.5) {}; % Point A
        \coordinate (C) at (current bounding box.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth} 
        \scalebox{0.65}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \tikzset{point/.style = {circle, fill=black, draw=black, inner sep=2pt}} % Points
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](-0.5,0)--(6,0) node[right]{$x$}; % Axis X
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](0,-0.5)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$}; % Axis Y
        \node[point, label=above:B] (B) at (2.5,2.5) {}; % Point B
        \coordinate (D) at (current bounding box.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
          \path[->,red,thick] ($(C)!0.65!(A)$) edge [bend right] ($(D)!0.65!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This works like a charm, also nice solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `scale` and `transform shape` for scale the label of the node.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}    
        %\scalebox{0.65}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65,transform shape,remember picture]
        \tikzset{point/.style = {circle, fill=black, draw=black, inner sep=2pt}} % Points
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](-0.5,0)--(6,0) node[right]{$x$}; % Axis X
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](0,-0.5)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$}; % Axis Y
        \node[point, label=above:A] (A) at (2.5,2.5) {}; % Point A
    \end{tikzpicture}
%}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth} 
        %\scalebox{0.65}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65,transform shape,remember picture]
        \tikzset{point/.style = {circle, fill=black, draw=black, inner sep=2pt}} % Points
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](-0.5,0)--(6,0) node[right]{$x$}; % Axis X
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth](0,-0.5)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$}; % Axis Y
        \node[point, label=above:B] (B) at (2.5,2.5) {}; % Point B
        \end{tikzpicture}
%}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
          \path[->,red,thick] (A) edge [bend right] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: scale and transform shape]

Comment: Thank you, this is way better that my solution, but I can still see one small issue, that the axis stayed thick.